# Rails AJAX request to controller method that then calls javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have looked at dozens of stack overflow posts and haven't found a solution that works which is why I'm reaching out for an otherwise well documented use case.

I have a button that that should do this.

- When clicked, call a custom controller method that updates the model and does other things
- Call a javascript function to update the page without reloading it (ajax)

Right now, the only way I am able to call a custom controller method is via this way which feels really hacky. I have stripped this down to as simple as possible.

routes.rb

`match 'admin/:id/toggleAdmin' => 'admin#toggleAdmin', via: [:patch, :put], as: :toggleAdmin`

list.html.erb

`<td><%= link_to "Toggle Admin", toggleAdmin_path(id: user.id), method: :patch %></td>`

admin_controller.rb

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  def toggleAdmin
    idToToggle = User.find(params[:id]).id
    if idToToggle == current_user.id
      redirect_to admin_list_path, danger: "You tried to make yourself a normal user! Don't do that!"
    else
      User.find(params[:id]).updateToAdmin()
      redirect_to admin_list_path, info: "The user with an ID of #{idToToggle} has had their admin attribute toggled!"
    end
  end
```

end

What I would like to do instead of reloading the page when an admin is toggled is to just use some javascript to rewrite that part of the dom.

What is a better way to go about this?

Here are just a few of the various resources I have already tried.

- [How to call a controller's method from a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307581/how-to-call-a-controllers-method-from-a-view)
- [Can we call a Controller's method from a view (as we call from helper ideally)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906527/can-we-call-a-controllers-method-from-a-view-as-we-call-from-helper-ideally)
- [Call controller method with rails-Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514956/call-controller-method-with-rails-ajax)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/7iyp6g/want_a_button_to_call_a_method_apparently_this_is/
- [How do I call a JavaScript function from an html.erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937676/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-from-an-html-erb)

Thanks for the help.

--- Edit for more information.

Using a clean rails app I now have the ability to call a controller method more cleanly but I am not getting an ajax request to go through that updates the page to show that the action was completed. (I am expecting a boolean value change and a flash). Here is the following relevant code:

users.js

```
$("#edit-form").html("<%= j render partial: 'form', locals: { user: @user } %>")
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for user do |form| %>
  <%= user.admin %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Toggle Admin", toggle_admin_user_path(user), method: :put, remote: true %>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing User</h1>

<div id="edit-form">
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { user: @user } %>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Show', @user %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', users_path %>
```

users_controller.rb Note that I have only included the `toggle_admin` and a couple other methods as the rest are just scaffolding.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :toggle_admin]

  def toggle_admin
    if 1 == 1
      logger.info "This is from info"
      u = User.find(params[:id])
      u.admin = !(u.admin)
      u.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { flash[:info] = "The user with an ID of #{@user.id} has had their admin attribute toggled!" }
      end
    else
      redirect_to admin_list_path, danger: "You tried to make yourself a normal user! Don't do that!"
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.fetch(:user, {})
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The routing

First thing, if you need a nested custom route inside a resource you can define it as a member of this resource:

```
resources :users do
  put 'toggle_admin', on: :member
end
```

which returns:

```
toggle_admin    PUT    /users/:id/toggle(.:format)    users#toggle
```

Second, your method names should be in snake_case : `def toggle_admin`
[See "Instance Methods" section](https://gist.github.com/alexpchin/f5d2be2ef3735889d315)

#### The controller

If you just want to update a user to admin (guessing by this method here: `User.find(params[:id]).updateToAdmin()`), you can define the custom `toggle_admin`method inside the `UsersController`.

Your custom method for triggering ajax request should respond to the js format and point to the corresponding js view (`toggle_admin.js.erb`)
As a member of the resource `User`, you can add it to the `before_action` callback to return the right user when you call the method.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :toggle_admin]
  #...
  def toggle_admin
    if #some condition
      # do some logic here
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js { flash[:info] = "The user with an ID of #{@user.id} has had their admin attribute toggled!" }
      end
    else
      redirect_to admin_list_path, danger: "You tried to make yourself a normal user! Don't do that!"
    end
  end
end
```

#### The view

In rails views, when you want to use ajax to update a view without reload, you need to use partial. It's this partial which will be refreshed inside the `.js.erb` file on a specific DOM element.

Let's make an example for the user#edit view.
First you need to render the view inside a partial `form` for example, and wrap it into a div with specific `id`:
*edit.html.erb*

```
<div id="edit-form">
  <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { user: @user } %>
</div>
```

The partial:
*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for user do |form| %>
  # the form
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Toggle Admin", toggle_admin_user_path(user), method: :put, remote: true %> 
# don't forget the remote: true for the ajax call
```

Finally the `.js.erb` for the custom action (assuming you have jquery):
*toggle_admin.js.erb*

```
$("#edit-form").html("<%= j render partial: 'form', locals: { user: @user } %>")
```

And voilà ! when click the link, you refresh the edit view with new informations from the controller without reloading the view.

Of course, this is an example for a classic resource's edit view but you can adapt it for any case. Just keep the good naming between routes, controllers, controller methods and views (AdminController, list view etc...)

---

#### Edit

To handle the flash messages, you need to add inside your layout > application.html.erb :

```
  <body>
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "classname" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. However, I am unable to get it working on a fresh project. I continue getting a syntax error in the controller part. `/home/frillybob/demo/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' format.js { info: "The user with an ID of #{idT ^ /home/frillybob/demo/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end ir admin attribute toggled!" } ^ /home/frillybob/demo/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:86: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: When starting from scratch I get the above error. When commenting out the `info:` part at line 8, I then get an error in the controller `Couldn't find User with id=edit`. Searching online had me go back to devise like in my main app. That was a lost cause, however, as I have no idea how to fix the myriad of errors there.

Comment: @frillybob for the first error, i fixed it inside my answer. For the `Couldn't find User with id=edit` error, it's just about params. It came from the user here : `toggle_admin_user_path(user)`.  What is the view's url ? what params do you have inside your logs when you click on the link ? can you edit your question with the view code to see what params you send to the controller ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I use /users/1/edit I am able to click toggle_admin and have that method execute. That was a simple mistake on me. However, I do not re-render the page without a reload. In the console I get an error No template found for UsersController#toggle_admin, rendering head :no_content I also get no flash message. I will update the original post with some more info. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @frillybob your template must have the same name as the method. Just rename your `users.js` to `toggle_admin.js.erb` (the js file need the erb suffix to be able handle the embedded ruby syntax (e.g. `<%= ... %>`)

Comment: Thanks for the response. That fixes the console error about the partial, however, the flash and attribute aren't updating. (The attribute does updates upon a page refresh). The console does say it rendered the js page `Rendered users/toggle_admin.js.erb (2.7ms)`. I was able to get javascript to trigger on click with just a simple `alert("hello world")` instead of the re-render of the form.

Comment: to handle the flash messages i made an edit of my post. For the refresh toggle, i made a demo app and i didn't be able to reproduce your error. My edit partial refresh without reload the `<%= user.admin %>` to true/false everytime i click on "Toggle"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170929/discussion-between-frillybob-and-sovalina).

Comment: I think SO is having issues. I cannot comment on our thread anymore. I still cannot get it figured out. I will pick it up tomorrow.